# Debug android app using windows Android

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

I'm asking about debugging android app(connect virtual device to adb) which this virtual device is the ( "windows android application" ) you can found it here : [Download](https://mega.co.nz/#!BUUHDTZb!DP3bLVzL0FhI7378KmWB5l664xlBwmZTLa5a12dmQ_I) :

I have some idea may you can use it but i tried the first one, 
because i didn't have enough knowledge it doesn't work for me.

Idea:
1- Trying to connect it over network. >>> tried it but not work with me may work with you.
2- Trying to have a fake usb connection.

Any other idea you have either it work or not please write it may other one can applied it.

Note: 
"windowsAndroid" application is power full and fast android i read about it, it doesn't have an emulator layer so it too fast, now site under maintenance Here : [www.socketeq.com](http://www.socketeq.com/) :
it install android ice-Cream sandwich 4.0.3 >>>>> These most important information I have.

Sorry for my poor English.

I'm waiting for your professorial solutions.
Thanks in advance.